# Why does this GLSL shader work fine with a GeForce but flickers strangely on an Intel HD 4000?

Tags: opengl, glsl, intel, opengl-3

Using OpenGL 3.3 core profile, I'm rendering a full-screen "quad" (as a single oversized triangle) via **gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3)** with the following shaders.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
#line 1

vec4 vx_Quad_gl_Position () {
    const float extent = 3;
    const vec2 pos[3] = vec2[](vec2(-1, -1), vec2(extent, -1), vec2(-1, extent));
    return vec4(pos[gl_VertexID], 0, 1);
}

void main () {
    gl_Position = vx_Quad_gl_Position();
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
#line 1
out vec3 out_Color;

vec3 fx_RedTest (const in vec3 vCol) {
    return vec3(0.9, 0.1, 0.1);
}

vec3 fx_Grayscale (const in vec3 vCol) {
    return vec3((vCol.r * 0.3) + (vCol.g * 0.59) + (vCol.b * 0.11));

}

void main () {
    out_Color = fx_RedTest(out_Color);
    out_Color = fx_Grayscale(out_Color);
}
```

Now, the code may look a bit odd and the present purpose of this may seem useless, but that shouldn't phase the GL driver.

On a GeForce, a get a gray screen as expected. That is, the "grayscale effect" applied to the hard-coded color "red" (0.9, 0.1, 0.1).

However, Intel HD 4000 [driver 9.17.10.2932 (12-12-2012) version -- the newest as of today] always, repeatedly shows nothing but the following constantly-flickering noise pattern: [image: shot01]

Now, just to experiment a little, I changed the fx_Grayscale() function around a little bit -- effectively it should be yielding the same visual result, just with slightly different coding:

```
vec3 fx_Grayscale (const in vec3 vCol) {

    vec3 col = vec3(0.9, 0.1, 0.1);
    col = vCol;
    float x = (col.r * 0.3) + (col.g * 0.59) + (col.b * 0.11);
    return vec3(x, x, x);
}
```

Again, Nvidia does the correct thing whereas Intel HD now always, repeatedly produces a rather different, but still constantly-flickering noise pattern: [image: shot02]

Must I suspect (yet another) Intel GL driver bug, or do you see any issues with my GLSL code -- **not from a prettiness perspective** (it's part of a shader code-gen experimental project) but from a mere **spec-correctness** point of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it looks strange to send in a "out" color as parameter to another function. I would rewrite it something like this:

```
void main () {
    vec3 col = vec3(0f,0f,0f);
    col = fx_RedTest(col);
    col = fx_Grayscale(col);
    out_Color = col;
}
```

Does it make any difference?

Comment: You're right it "looks strange", I thought the same -- but then I thought, either it's permissable by the spec and then the driver should be capable of it, or it's forbidden and then both drivers should error. Oh well, in an ideal world  ;)  Indeed your work-around makes it work with Intel HD. Sheesh, Intel should just give up on implementing GL... or hire some Nvidia/AMD engineers... well thanks for compelling me to try what I already suspected but previously didn't want to accept as possible  ;)

Comment: @metaleap: Note that it is perfectly legal in GLSL to read from `out` global variables. That Intel's driver doesn't allow it is none too surprising.