# Why does this GLSL shader not working on Intel G41?

Tags: opengl, glsl, intel

Some info about my graphic card:
GL_RENDERER: **Intel(R) G41 Express Chipset**
OpenGL_VERSION: **2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.1986**
GLSL_VERSION: **1.20 - Intel Build 8.15.10.1986**

Vertex shader 1:

```
#version 110
attribute vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 vertex;

void light(inout vec3 ver, out vec3 nor);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1.0);
    light(vertex, normal);
}
```

Vertex shader 2:

```
#version 110

void light(inout vec3 ver, out vec3 nor)
{
    ver = vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    //vec3 v = -ver;  // wrong line
    nor = vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    //float f = dot(ver, nor);  // wrong line
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 110

varying vec3 normal;
varying vec3 vertex;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vertex, 1.0);
}
```

These shaders works well if the two lines are commented in second vertex shader. However, once one of them is enabled, we get a error. The error occur in opengl function **glDrawArrays**.

It seems that variable of **out/inout** can not used as right value.
I have run the same program on **Intel HD Graphics 3000** which opengl's version is **3.1** and GLSL's version is **1.4**, and the program works well. Is this a bug of Intel's driver or just wrong used by me?

Comment: What error do you get? Do you get a shader compilation error? Are you linking these shaders together properly?

Comment: I get a error dialog(Visual Studio 2010) when execute glDrawArrays(). "Unhandled exception at 0x10173169 in xx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xbaadf00d." I think the compilation and link of those shaders are right. Here is a same problem I find.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834180/why-does-this-glsl-shader-work-fine-with-a-geforce-but-flickers-strangely-on-an)

Answer (score 0):

Because intel g41 is an extremely weak gpu.
The only way through it is to upgrade your gpu.

Comment: It would be better if you can add this kind of an information as a comment rather than an answer.